# Multiple update, delete< insert ?

Tags: веб-программирование, база-данных, yii

Здравствуйте! В Yii новичок. Не ругайте! Просто хочу сделать правильно.

Пример: пользователь отмечает из select (multiple) нужные элементы. Далее, после сохранения, он хочет их изменить, некоторые удалить или добавить новые.

**Вопросы:** 
1. Как удалить уже текущие элементы, которые есть в БД, которые пользователь снял с них галочки в multiple?
2. Как добавить новые?
3. Как пропустить уже те, которые есть в БД?

Делать это стандартно if else или есть другие варианты?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Удаляем ВСЕ, которые он до этого сохранил. Записываем ВСЕ вновь выбранные. 2 операции. Никаких сравнений на существование производить не нужно. Не усложняйте)

Comment: Также подумал потом! Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

> Пример: пользователь отмечает из
> select (multiple) нужные элементы.
> Далее, после сохранения, он хочет их
> изменить, некоторые удалить или
> добавить новые.

Во многих современных фрейворках, включая Yii, есть так называемые [ORM](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ORM).
Вам стоит ознакомится с [Active Record](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.ar)

Вкратце, если запись существует, берете запись по идентификатору:

```
$post = Post::model()->findByPk({ID записи});
```

если нет, создаете новую

```
$post=new Post;
```

далее сериализуете массив данных (выбранных значений) и устанавливаете в ваше поле (допустим сhoice)

```
$post->choice = serialize($data);
```